# Javascript - Universal Windows App - Capture Close Event

Tags: javascript, events, uwp, win-universal-app

Within my app I have a flag saying if data needs saving or not `m_IsSaved`.

If the user closes the app when `m_IsSaved` is `false` I need to give them a warning message and give them the option to return to the app without closing.
Ie, if they click YES the app closes normally. If they click NO then the app stays open and does not close. (This will then give them the option to save their data. The save function is already written and works fine.)

How is this done in javascript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your description, it seems you want to prevent your UWP app from closing when `m_IsSaved` is `false`. However, this is not possible. For UWP apps, we can't prevent the app from suspending or closing.

Refer [App close](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/launch-resume/app-lifecycle#app-close):

> There is not an event to indicate that the user closed the app. When an app is closed by the user, it is first suspended to give you an opportunity to save its state.

So you can always save the data with [Application.Suspending](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/br242341) event (for WinJS app, it would be [WinJS.Application.oncheckpoint](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br229839.aspx) event). I think there is no need to prevent users from closing your app.

For more info, please see [Windows 10 universal Windows platform (UWP) app lifecycle](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/launch-resume/app-lifecycle).